# Transfer data from component to another in Angular

Tags: angular, search, filter, data-binding, components

Could you help me with a quick fix please ?

I have two component one for top navigation with search and the another is a card list. The goal is if user start typing the 'card list grid' start filter out. I have separated components and want to get the 'searchKeyword' from top bar component to the card list component thats all. I am new with angular so I am seeking for your help. Thanks in advance.

TOP BAR WITH SEARCH INPUT:

```
@Component({
selector: 'top-bar',
templateUrl: './top-bar.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./top-bar.component.scss']
})
export class TopBarComponent implements OnInit {

_searchKeyword: string;

constructor(
   public employeeService: EmployeeService,
   private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
) { }

ngOnInit(): void { }
}
```

TOP BAR HTML:

```
 <div id="top-search" class="right-container w-1/4">
  <input
    class="w-full px-2 py-1 rounded-md"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Search"
    [(ngModel)]="_searchKeyword"/>
</div>
```

CARD LIST:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'card-list',
  templateUrl: './card-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card-list.component.scss']
 })
 export class CardListComponent implements OnInit {

employees: Employee[] | any[] = [];
filteredEmployees: Employee[] | any[] = [];

@Input() _searchKeyword: string;

constructor(
   private employeeService: EmployeeService,
   private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
   private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.employees = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data['employee'];
   this.filteredEmployees = this.employees;
   console.log(this._searchKeyword)
}

get searchKeyword(): string {
   return this._searchKeyword;
}

set searchKeyword(userInput: string) {
   this._searchKeyword = userInput;
   this.filteredEmployees = this.filterEmployees(userInput);
}

filterEmployees(userInput: string): any {
   console.log(userInput)
   return this.employees.filter(em => em.firstname.toLowerCase()
      .indexOf(userInput.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
   }  
}
```

CARD LIST HTML:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-card gap-8 pb-6">
   <card-item
     *ngFor="let employee of filteredEmployees" [employee]="employee">
   </card-item>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you pass  `_searchKeyword` to card list component? I see an @Input() but how is this used? I dont see any connection in the files you shared between these 2 components. If these components are not parent child, you can use a service to pass data from one component to another

Comment: Check this https://levelup.gitconnected.com/5-ways-to-share-data-between-angular-components-d656a7eb7f96. I think it will help you

Comment: Thank you for help everybody. Learning always a good treat imho. Thanks!